# can bazaar ignore a file that already exists in a branch?

Tags: bazaar

On my local machine the configurations are different from the test and production server.

Everytime when I want to commit my local code, it notices (Bazaar Explorer) that I edited the config file. Now I'm explicitly ignoring this file with every commit. However, this goes wrong once in a while.

Using branch or user ignores doesn't solve the problem. The file is already in the trunk.

Does somebody have a good strategy, workaround or perhaps found the right parameter for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Don't version-control the actual config file. If you want to version-control a config sample, give it another name. 
So do something like this:

```
bzr remove --keep conf.ini
bzr ignore conf.ini
cp conf.ini conf.sample.ini
<maybe edit the new sample to be generic>
bzr add conf.sample.ini
bzr ci -m "don't track the actual conf file any more"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alias bzr commit to use exclude like:

alias bzrcom='bzr commit --exclude=/path/to/your/config'